# Prestashop 1.6 Show manufacturer description on product page

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I want to show product description on product page. 
Is posible to change product.tpl to show it? Is necessary to develop a module or change core clases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the manufacturer description on product page, the best way is to create an override to ProductController like:

```
class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore
{
    public function initContent(){

        $manufacturer_description = "";
        if($this->product->id_manufacturer > 0)
        {
            $manufacturer = new Manufacturer($this->product->id_manufacturer, $this->context->language->id);
            $manufacturer_description = $manufacturer->description;
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign('manufacturer_description', $manufacturer_description);

        parent::initContent();
    }
}
```

Then in the product.tpl of the theme place the {$manufacturer_description} where you want it to show.

Don't forget to clear cache, and delete the file cache/class_index.php after these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

For me it has been OK to put this on template product-details.tpl, overriding the original:

{$product_manufacturer->description nofilter}

The "nofilter" tag was needed to avoid html being displayed on browser

This is for the version 1.7